# Стабильность карты на андроид устройствах

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, flutter, яндекс-карты, yandexmapkit

https://disk.yandex.com/i/IGd2iYTKcDc-pw   видео обзор на андроид
https://disk.yandex.com/i/Mx8F5kmldD4bww   видео обзор на ios

У меня проблема с яндекс картами, сама карта у меня под виджетом flexible и при раскрытии верхнего блока или нажатии кнопки карта на весь экран flex изменится. Проблема сама карта на андроиде очень медлено работает и местами глючит. Ниже отправлю логи при глюке карты

Другая проблема на физическом телефона андроид только один маркер показывает (точнее самого последнего из листа с маркерами хотя принтом показывает что количесто 15)

Логи когда карта не работает :

E/BufferQueueProducer( 4851): SurfaceTexture-0-4851-2 dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has no connected producer